# How to click link on the page using VBScript

Tags: internet-explorer, vbscript, click

I am trying to automate my network reboot.
This is the location image to click on highlighted in red.
[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lEVSY.png)

This is the HTML beneath:

```
<ul id="main_menu" style="width: 510px; padding-left: 32px; padding-right: 32px;">
    <li id="mm0" class="m1_status"><a href="devinfo.html" class="selected"><span>Gateway Status</span></a></li>
   <li id="mm2" class="m1_wireless"><a href="wifibasic.html" class=""><span>Wireless Setup</span></a></li>
   <li id="mm3" class="m1_advanced"><a href="lan.html" class=""><span>Advanced Setup</span></a></li> 
   <li id="mm4" class="m1_secu"><a href="password.html" class=""><span>Security Setup</span></a></li> 
   <li id="mm6" class="m1_utilities"><a href="reboot.html" class=""><span>Utilities</span></a></li> 
   <li id="mm7" class="m1_support"><a href="iptvmulticast.html" class=""><span>Support Console</span> 
 </a></li>
```

I need to click on it to take my next action.
Here is the code I have tried:

```
IE.Document.getElementById("mm6").Click()
```

This is the error I get line 25: **Object required: 'Document.getElementByID(...)'**

Here is my full code. It works fine up to line 24:

```
Dim Helem

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = 1 
IE.navigate "http://192.168.1.1/login.html"

While IE.Busy
    Wscript.Sleep 100
Wend

Do Until IE.ReadyState = 4
 WScript.Sleep 100
Loop
IE.Document.getElementByID("username").value = "user"
IE.Document.getElementByID("password").value = "pass"
Do Until IE.ReadyState = 4
 WScript.Sleep 100
Loop
IE.Document.getElementById("btn_login").Click()
Do Until IE.ReadyState = 4
 WScript.Sleep 100
Loop
WScript.Sleep 5000
IE.Document.getElementById("mm6").Click()
```

I really appreciate any help or suggestions to make.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is due to you don't locate the element correctly. If you want to click the link, you need to click the element `<a>` not element `<li>`. Please refer to the following code to click the element:

```
IE.Document.querySelector("li#mm6 a").Click
```